# datanucleus + jpa + oracle. Strange error with tables not existing

Tags: oracle, jpa, datanucleus

I have a strange issue when I try to use Datanucleus to access an Oracle database.
In short, what happens is this :

- I run my application; when datanucleus initializes, it complains that it cannot find the tables (although they are in there).
- I stop the application, I drop the tables, I add the

  ```
  datanucleus.autoCreateSchema = true
  ```

  ...property in persistence.xml, and everything works - tables are created and then the select works.
- I stop the application again, and then I try to start it with the above parameter disabled.
- The error comes back although it was Datanucleus who created the tables in the first place, and now it complains it can't find them.
- also please note that the same setup works with a postgresql database behind, without issues.

Can somebody please help ?

A few details about my setup :

- I'm using Oracle thin driver.
- My entity classes are annotated like this :

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "tablename1", schema = "schema2000")
  ```
- Please note that everything works OK if I remove the schema=... from annotation
- Error message is :

  ```
  16:05:40,216 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Setting autocommit=false to connection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@1dff2e1b
  16:05:40,216 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@1dff2e1b" opened with isolation level "read-committed"
  16:05:40,904 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - Check of existence of schema2000.tablename1 returned table type of null
  16:05:40,905 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema] - An error occurred while auto-creating schema elements - rolling back
  16:05:41,109 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@1dff2e1b" non enlisted to a transaction is being committed.
  16:05:41,110 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@1dff2e1b" closed
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Required table missing : "schema2000.tablename1" in Catalog "" Schema "schema2000". DataNucleus requires this table to perform its persistence operations. Either your MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.autoCreateTables"
  at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:274)
  at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.merge(JPAEntityManager.java:519)
  ```

Comment: Have you ruled out Oracle permission problems?  Can you select from the table using a SQL client connected with the same user that DataNucleus is using?

Comment: Yes, permission problems are ruled out, due to the fact that if I create the tables AND do a SELECT in the same run, it works correctly. The part that bothers me is that if I run it again with "autoCreateSchema" disabled, it does not work anymore.

Comment: After you've run with 'autoCreateSchema' you've connected to the db with a SQL client using the application credentials and you can select from the table?

Comment: Yes, I did that, and I can see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest you look closer at case-sensitivity of your identifiers. DataNucleus logs what the JDBC driver allows with a line like

> Supported Identifier Cases : "MixedCase" UPPERCASE "MixedCase-Sensitive"

so possibly it requires the schema in UPPERCASE or maybe quoted (all RDBMS are different, and inclusive some differ depending on the operating system they're running on)

Obviously embedding datastore-specific info in annotations is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks man, that was it. I changed my identifiers to all uppercase and it now works like a charm.
This does look however like a bug. If I use Datanucleus to create tables/schema, then I would have expected it to work.
Also, in a regular client, I can do selects, etc, in whichever cases I choose (even mixed). So do you know if there is an option for telling datanucleus to do the same ?
Please note I cannot award the bounty now - I need to wait 22 hours to pass.

Comment: You could tell them to use mixed case/case insensitive instead of having to adhere to the defaults