# datanucleus + postgresql + jpql error in simple update clause

Tags: jpa, datanucleus

I have tried to fix this for 6 hours now, and I couldn't for the life of me figure it out.

I'm using :

- datanucleus 3.2.1, with JPA
- PostgreSQL 8.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-10), 64-bit
- postgres jdbc driver version : 9.1-901.jdbc4

I'm trying to execute a very simple update query through jpql. Query is basically :

```
UPDATE MyClass x SET x.recordStatus='0' where x.token='1234'
```

My code looks like this :

```
    String updateClause = "UPDATE MyClass x SET x.recordStatus='0' where x.token='1234'";
    EntityManager entityManager = getDefaultEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(updateClause);
    query.executeUpdate();
    entityManager.close();
```

The problem that I have is that an error is thrown from the driver

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "a0" of relation "my_class" does not exist
                                Position: 42
                                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
                                    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
```

This is somehwat normal, in terms that postgres accepts updates in the form :

```
update some_table x set field=value where field2=another_value
```

...but not

```
update some_table x set x.field=value where x.field2=another_value
```

(i.e. no aliases in SET or WHERE clause when executing an update)

I have tried writing my jpql query :

- without using aliases in SET and WHERE clauses (update MyClass x set recordStatus='0' where token='1234'), but the logs show me that datanucleus compiles the query into a native query that uses aliases anyway.
- without using aliases at all (not even for the class name), but in this case datanucleus throws me an error that I must have an alias.

For a complete list of dependencies, please see the end of this post.

My questions are :

- How can I overcome this problem ? What am I doing wrong ?
- A very basic use case of an important feature, fails with Datanucleus. This is not the first time things like this happen. For example see this post : [datanucleus + jpa + oracle. Strange error with tables not existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764904/datanucleus-jpa-oracle-strange-error-with-tables-not-existing)
  I also have other examples.
  This doesn't look very good, and I don't understand why, because I really couldn't find other posts complaining about this type of problems. Is this combination(datanucleus + postgres) really that unused ? It almost looks abandoned.

Thank you for your time.
Kind regards,
Andrei

My list of dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-release</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-release</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-connectionpool</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If you have some problem with some software I personally would raise an issue on that software and show the people who write it how to demonstrate it (because maybe they don't see it, or haven't come across your use-case). That would likely be more productive than calling things "trashy" on other sites. I've used PostgreSQL many times with DataNucleus over the last 3 years and never had a problem, but not done a bulk UPDATE; maybe there is some issue with the syntax they use, and that works for many but not for Postgresql? Don't think JDO is 2.2 btw ... 3.0.1 is what I use.

Comment: Admittedly, calling it trashy is not the best choice of words. However, that's exactly the problem. I don't have a very special use case. I just want the most basic update through jpql use case to work. Reworded the text, so as not to offend anyone :) Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this request : UPDATE MyClass SET recordStatus='0' where token='1234'

Comment: I did. It complains that I have no alias (datanucleus exception)